# Will oversampling lead to an overfitted model?

Tags: python, model, classification, oversampling

The target attribute distribution is currently like this:

```
mydata.groupBy("Churn").count().show()

+-----+-----+
|Churn|count|
+-----+-----+
|    1|  483|
|    0| 2850|
+-----+-----+
```

My questions are:

- methods of oversampling like: *manully, smote, adasyn* are going to use available data to create new data points?
- If we use such data to train a classification model, will it not be an overfitted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is any method of oversampling (manully, smote, adasyn) will use the available data to create new data points.

- Data imbalance problems is mostly handled in three steps:

  1. Over-sample the minority class.
  2. Under-sample the majority class.
  3. Synthesize new minority classes.

SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling TEchnique) is coming under the third step. It’s the process of creating a new minority classes from the datasets.

The process in SMOTE is mentioned below:

[image]

So, this is a bit *smarter* than just over-sampling.

> If we use such data to build a classification model, will it not be an overfitted one?

The correct answer would be *PROBABLY*. Give it a try!

This is why we use *test sets* and *cross validation* to try to understand if the model would be good with unseen data!